# QuercusCompiledScript.eval output not working

Tags: quercus

I cannot figure out what the problem is with the QuercusCompiledScript.eval. Running code:

```
QuercusScriptEngine quercusScriptEngine = new QuercusScriptEngine();
quercusScriptEngine.eval("<?php echo 'hello uncompiled!\n'; ?>");
CompiledScript script = quercusScriptEngine.compile("<?php echo 'hello compiled!\n'; ?>");
script.eval();
System.out.println("that's all");
```

produces:

```
hello uncompiled!
that's all
```

Debugging this stuff I could not figure out what's wrong, as it does execute the statement, buffers are OK, but the output itself is not performed.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem. The `QuercusScriptEngine.eval()` explicitly does `writer.flush()` in the end referring to the http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=1914. But the `QuercusCompiledScript.eval()` does not, at least in the quercus-4.0.39 (and in the quercus-4.0.45 as well). The workaround is to flush explicitly providing a `Writer`:

```
CompiledScript script = quercusScriptEngine.compile("<?php echo 'hello compiled!\n'; ?>");
ScriptContext ctx = quercusScriptEngine.getContext();
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
ctx.setWriter(writer);
script.eval(ctx);
writer.flush();
```